# What can cause delete to loop Sleep()ing and never return in the Borland / Embarcadero RTL?

Tags: delphi, memory, sleep, c++builder, fastmm

I have an odd bug where when deleting one specific object, `delete` never returns.  Instead, it appears to spend its time calling `Sleep()` in a permanent loop.  Here's the call stack:

```
:7723fd71 ntdll.ZwDelayExecution + 0x15
:767c4498 KERNELBASE.Sleep + 0xf
:21495359 BORLNDMM.@Borlndmm@SysFreeMem$qqrpv + 0xb5
:32aaa3e5 CC32100MT._free + 0xd
:32a020b2 CC32100MT.@$bdele$qpv + 0x1e
[My code]
```

Running, it returns back to `SysFreeMem` (never back to `free`) and calls `Sleep` again from within `SysFreeMem`, permanently looping.

My code is pretty simple: it's a VCL event handler, a spinbox has just changed and a settings object updated, and the temporary settings it made are being deleted:

```
delete poNewSettings;
```

This code hasn't changed for a year or two, nor has the settings class for a while, which is basically a giant struct-like object containing lots of settings.  It has a compiler-generated destructor.  Stepping through the code shows a number of calls deleting strings and other std:: objects, and then it appears to freeze when stepping into the next function (that is, at the end of `~basic_string()`, pressing F7 at the closing brace `}`), which the IDE never shows.  The freeze is that it's inside Sleep().  This code is running in the main thread.

I tried using the CPU view to deduce the delay Sleep() was being called with, but could not spot it - I am not completely up on x86 assembly code, I'm afraid.

One other thread is inside `Sleep`, probably related to COM (the app is a COM server, although nothing is using COM at the moment).  Its entire call stack is:

```
:7723fd71 ntdll.ZwDelayExecution + 0x15
:767c4498 KERNELBASE.Sleep + 0xf
:74c7d98d ; C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
:74c7d87a ; C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
:768133aa kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12
:77259ef2 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63
:77259ec5 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36
```

One other thread is doing something and actively allocating and freeing memory and calling `Sleep()` too - a background task is running which is checking if it needs to work (it doesn't have to) and is sleeping for 100ms to check again.  The allocation and free is for a string for a folder path.  While there are other threads in the program, they are all blocked waiting for something to do, this time using `WaitForSingleObject` or similar.  This background task thread wakes (returns from Sleep) once every 100ms; I don't see (yet!) how it could affect another thread's `delete`.

No other threads are deleting or allocating anything, as far as I can tell.  I put breakpoints in `CC32100MT._malloc`, `CC32100MT._free` and `CC32100MT._realloc`.  No others break when running, and when paused to inspect, no other threads are inside any of those calls.

**What could be the cause of delete looping and not returning?**

I am using:
* RAD Studio 2010, fully updated
* Application is mostly C++ (C++ Builder) with small bits of Delphi.
* Because it's using the Embarcadero RTL, I think it is using FastMM

I have added the Delphi tag since it's using the Embarcadero RTL and FastMM, which are used by Delphi people a lot more than by C++ people.

Comment: It sounds like you might have heap corruption with a circular loop in a list of free heap blocks. I'm not familiar with C++Builder - are you able to enable the FastMM debug flags from that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I'm not sure about FastMM debug mode.  I *think* that it uses a C implementation of fastMM - I've seen one in the RTL source folders before - not the Delphi implementation.  I frankly don't know enough about the internals to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure you can trust the debugger in the RAD Studio IDE in this case to properly name the Kernel symbols involved.

I think you should step into the place where this happens and then examine the variable you're freeing and see if it has been corrupted.

IF the variable you're freeing is a class you defined yourself I usually like to add Guard fields to the beginning and end of the object.

```
class TMyPOSettings {
  public:
    ...
  private:
    int Guard1;
    // all my other instance data 
    int Guard2
};
```

In the constructor I set the guards to MAGIC1 and MAGIC2 which I defined somewhere,
and in the destructor I set the guards to MAGIC_FREE_1 and MAGIC_FREE_2.

Then I can see if I've repeated the destruction of the same object, or if some other thing is overwriting my heap memory at that location.

I wonder if it is possible that what you're debugging is in fact the results of the code after a serious exception is caught inside Windows, aborting whatever it was that your thread was doing, and basically now doing nothing until your process terminates.  The first place I would debug is single stepping through your destructor's code and seeing what it does.

Comment: Thanks Warren.  As far as I can tell it's not corrupted (and it's only created two lines above!)  I shall keep investigating...